# Running transformers on docker

Tags: huggingface-transformers

Why this works in google colab but doesn't work on docker?

So this is my Dockerfile.

```
FROM python:3.7
RUN pip install -q transformers tensorflow 
RUN pip install ipython
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash"]
```

And I'm executing this.

```py
from transformers import *
nlp = pipeline(
    'question-answering', 
    model='mrm8488/distill-bert-base-spanish-wwm-cased-finetuned-spa-squad2-es',
    tokenizer=(
        'mrm8488/distill-bert-base-spanish-wwm-cased-finetuned-spa-squad2-es',  
        {"use_fast": False}
    )
)
```

But I get this error

```
   ...:                                                                                                                                                                             
Downloading: 100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 465/465 [00:00<00:00, 325kB/s]
Downloading: 100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 242k/242k [00:00<00:00, 796kB/s]
Downloading: 100%|█████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 112/112 [00:00<00:00, 70.1kB/s]
Downloading: 100%|█████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 135/135 [00:00<00:00, 99.6kB/s]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/modeling_tf_utils.py in from_pretrained(cls, pretrained_model_name_or_path, *model_args, **kwargs)
    461                 if resolved_archive_file is None:
--> 462                     raise EnvironmentError
    463             except EnvironmentError:

OSError: 

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-1f9fed95967a> in <module>
      5     tokenizer=(
      6         'mrm8488/distill-bert-base-spanish-wwm-cased-finetuned-spa-squad2-es',
----> 7         {"use_fast": False}
      8     )
      9 )

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/pipelines.py in pipeline(task, model, config, tokenizer, framework, **kwargs)
   1882                 "Trying to load the model with Tensorflow."
   1883             )
-> 1884         model = model_class.from_pretrained(model, config=config, **model_kwargs)
   1885 
   1886     return task_class(model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer, modelcard=modelcard, framework=framework, task=task, **kwargs)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/modeling_tf_auto.py in from_pretrained(cls, pretrained_model_name_or_path, *model_args, **kwargs)
   1207         for config_class, model_class in TF_MODEL_FOR_QUESTION_ANSWERING_MAPPING.items():
   1208             if isinstance(config, config_class):
-> 1209                 return model_class.from_pretrained(pretrained_model_name_or_path, *model_args, config=config, **kwargs)
   1210         raise ValueError(
   1211             "Unrecognized configuration class {} for this kind of TFAutoModel: {}.\n"

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/modeling_tf_utils.py in from_pretrained(cls, pretrained_model_name_or_path, *model_args, **kwargs)
    467                     f"- or '{pretrained_model_name_or_path}' is the correct path to a directory containing a file named one of {TF2_WEIGHTS_NAME}, {WEIGHTS_NAME}.\n\n"
    468                 )
--> 469                 raise EnvironmentError(msg)
    470             if resolved_archive_file == archive_file:
    471                 logger.info("loading weights file {}".format(archive_file))

OSError: Can't load weights for 'mrm8488/distill-bert-base-spanish-wwm-cased-finetuned-spa-squad2-es'. Make sure that:

- 'mrm8488/distill-bert-base-spanish-wwm-cased-finetuned-spa-squad2-es' is a correct model identifier listed on 'https://huggingface.co/models'

- or 'mrm8488/distill-bert-base-spanish-wwm-cased-finetuned-spa-squad2-es' is the correct path to a directory containing a file named one of tf_model.h5, pytorch_model.bin.
```

However this works perfectly in [google colab](https://colab.research.google.com/github/mrm8488/shared_colab_notebooks/blob/master/Using_Spanish_BERT_fine_tuned_for_Q%26A_pipelines.ipynb#scrollTo=keZfuUAUlYNT). This Google Colab doesn't require GPU to be ran, so why wouldn't it work in docker? What dependencies could I be missing? It doesn't see in the error message that dependencies could be missing, more than the model is no there but look:
And yes, this model exists [`"mrm8488/distill-bert-base-spanish-wwm-cased-finetuned-spa-squad2-es"`](https://huggingface.co/mrm8488/distill-bert-base-spanish-wwm-cased-finetuned-spa-squad2-es) in hugging.co

Comment: Do you have a local clone of said model in the Colab instance? Otherwise, I suspect that the download path on your docker container may differ from the standard installation location of `transformers`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61798573/where-does-hugging-faces-transformers-save-models) for reference of the download folder.

Comment: @dennlinger Hmm no, the Google Colab script doesn't seem to require a google drive connection or GPU, maybe it's an enviroment variable?

Comment: I don't think it has to do anything with the GPU, and even without google Drive, my suspicion would be that Docker has the `~/.cache` directory somewhere else, where huggingface isn't looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is that Docker doesn't store a cache-- it isn't persistent between runs-- and Hugging Face doesn't automatically download the model files without that cache.

You can/should mount a storage folder (like "hf_cache" or something similar) in your project directory. Then set your environment variable in the Dockerfile like so:

```
# Set the environment variable for the Hugging Face cache directory
ENV TRANSFORMERS_CACHE=/hf_cache
```

Then mount the cache directory like this:

```
docker run -v $(pwd)/hf_cache:/hf_cache hf_image
```

(Or if you're using pycharm, just use the Docker run configuration)

This tells docker to use your local cache file and lets you persist information between Docker runs, and HuggingFace can access/cache/reuse the downloaded models between runs.

I've run this locally on Docker and it works for me.

It's also good practice to include a requirements.txt file and direct Docker to download the contents: after resolving this issue, I then had to download a couple of dependencies.