# Where does hugginface's transform library look for models?

Tags: huggingface-transformers, pythonpath

I'm trying to make [huggingface](https://huggingface.co/)'s [transformer](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/index) library use a model that I have downloaded that is not in the [huggingface model](https://huggingface.co/models) repository.

Where does `transformers` look for models? Is there an equivalent of the `$PATH` environment variable for transformers models?

## Research

[This hugging face issues](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/2588) talks about manually downloading models.

[This issue](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/856#issuecomment-514239362) suggests that you can work around the question of where huggingface is looking for models by using the path as an argument to `from_pretrained`  (#model = BertModel.from_pretrained('path/to/your/directory')`)

## Related questions

- [Where does hugging face's transformers save models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61798573/where-does-hugging-faces-transformers-save-models)

Comment: you can actually specify a local path when loading with `.from_pretrained()`. Is there any hard requirement that you would natively look in a specific folder, or what does not work with that solution?

Comment: I think that works yes. I just sort of assumed that there was a "local" namespace for models as well as an internet one.. but it does seem to the case that local models work with paths.